# Pip Is Failing To Downgrade Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, upgrade

I need to downgrade numpy as a package I just installed upgraded numpy, which is now incompatible with several other packages.

However, the standard fix I have found online isn't working. I have run:

```
pip3 install numpy==1.19.5
```

and

```
pip3 install --upgrade numpy==1.19.5
```

but when I run `python3 -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"`, I still get `1.20.3`.

I get the message `Successfully installed numpy-1.19.5`, but I also get the error:

```
ERROR: pymatgen 2022.0.4 has requirement numpy>=1.20.1, but you'll have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
```

and so on, so I suspect this means the upgrade has been bypassed.

However, what's very confusing is that I have inspected the directory `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` and this nonetheless contains `numpy-1.19.5.dist-info`.

I have even tried the `--no-cache-dir -I` and `--force-reinstall` options,  no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I did some quick experimenting, and I found that if I meet these conditions:

1. Start the python kernel. I simply opened IDLE.
2. Install a new version of numpy or uninstall it altogether.
3. Run `import numpy` in the kernel that was running before uninstalling/updating numpy
4. Run `print(numpy.__version__)`

I get back the same version of numpy that I had installed when starting the kernel. I do not know exactly why this is.

If I then do the following:

1. Restart the shell (Press Ctrl + F6 in IDLE)
2. Run `import numpy`
3. Run `print(numpy.__version__)`

I get back the newly installed version of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue.

I had installed the software with python3 -m rather than pip3, so instead I ran:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy==1.19.5
```